# Generate and Save the files automatically to my local disk using Selenium

Tags: selenium, download

I have a Report Generator which is an intranet web application generates some reports. There are about 100 reports. Those reports are of PDF and Excel type. And I want to ensure that all these reports are generated without any issue. This is a daily job.

Each report takes an average of 2 min. Manual checking process takes 200 min. 
As this is a testing process and not bothered about the contents in the files I want to automate the process.

We are using Selenium test cases to test our web application. 
Is there any way to Save these reports on my location disk using Selenium ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no.  Browsers won't allow it, unless a user *chooses* to upload.  But even if there is a way, i would advise against using it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can do this by any means its **HIGHLY NOT RECOMMENDED**

This will be a huge security threat and it won't be allowed. Javascript is inside a security sandbox and won't allow these kind of things.

What if the server is sending a potentially dangerous file that might affect the client system?

See [**JavaScript security**](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-Security/)

Answer (score 0):

At best, you could display the file download prompt. The browser's security (and common sense :)) won't allow you to do anything more. If you absolutely must do unsupervised file downloads, you could use some kind of ActiveX, or a Java applet.